# How do i make a while loop so it reads through every single line in .txt file before it decide what to?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Im creating a function called addingcustomer(n):
so i need it to read through every single line in the .txt to make sure there is no repeated customer name only add the new customer name:
my customer.txt:

```
[1. "Yuvin Ng”, “Columbia College”, 778]
[2, “Ali”, “Douiglas College”, 77238]
```

my current function:

```
def addingcustomer(file_name,new_name):
    f=open(file_name,"r+")
    for line in f:
        while new_name in line:
            return ("The Customer existed")
        while new_name not in line:
            f=open("file_name","w")
            f.write(list(new_name)+"\n")
            f.close()
```

how can i create a while loop to make it function as a addition of a list to the current.txt file. 
im so sorry i tried my best and im stuck.

Comment: I fixed the indentation for you -- just add four spaces before every line in the code and it formats it nicely.

Comment: Er, I guess @zeekay fixed it before me. :)

Comment: You are using different types of quotes. Stick to the standard ones: "". Don't do something like: **"Yuvin Ng”**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need the two `while` statements.  Also, you need to close the file before you return.  Something like this:

```
def addingcustomer(file_name,new_name):
    f=open(file_name,"r+")
    for line in f:
        if new_name in line:
            f.close()
            return ("The Customer existed")
    # the name didn't exist
    f.write(str(list(new_name)+"\n")
    f.close()
    return ("Added new customer.")
```

If I were doing it, however, I'd return either `True` or `False` to indicate that a customer had been added:

```
def addingcustomer(file_name,new_name):
    f=open(file_name,"r+")
    for line in f:
        if new_name in line:
            f.close()
            return False
    # the name didn't exist
    f.write(new_name)
    f.write("\n")
    f.close()
    return True
```

A bigger question is, what format is `new_name` in to begin with?

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list # attempt to add non existed customer. 
I thought i changed new_name into a list so it can concatenate.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yuvinng\Desktop\Customer assignment 1\Customer assignment 2", line 77, in <module>
    function(c)
  File "C:\Users\Yuvinng\Desktop\Customer assignment 1\Customer assignment 2", line 26, in function
    print (addingcustomer("customerlist.txt",x))
  File "C:\Users\Yuvinng\Desktop\Customer assignment 1\Customer assignment 2", line 64, in addingcustomer
    f.write(list(new_name)+"\n")
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: ok i'm going to work on the script that you just gave me. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't think about the `"\n"` -- why do you need that?  I've edited the second part of my answer.

Comment: the reason i have "\n" so that when i add new customer name in my current customer.txt file it will have (eg.
[1. "Yuvin Ng”, “Columbia College”, 778]
[2, “Ali”, “Douiglas College”, 77238]
[3, "new customer name", "UBC" ,4930201133]

Comment: Yeah it work when i change (str(new_name)) instead of list. But what i wanted was a list. and i need to add the new customer information in new line not on the same line .

Comment: @Yuvin Ng -- try the latest edit I added.  I simply wrote the `"\n"` separately.

Comment: @Chriss Gregg 

i got error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yuvinng\Desktop\Customer assignment 1\Customer assignment 2", line 79, in <module>
    function(c)
  File "C:\Users\Yuvinng\Desktop\Customer assignment 1\Customer assignment 2", line 26, in function
    print (addingcustomer("customerlist.txt",x))
  File "C:\Users\Yuvinng\Desktop\Customer assignment 1\Customer assignment 2", line 65, in addingcustomer
    f.write(list(new_name))
TypeError: must be str, not list

Comment: i think the problem now is with (list(new_name))

Comment: @Yuvin Ng -- what type is `new_name`?  If it is a string, you need to do some processing right from the start, to get it into the same form as the lines you are reading in from the file.  If new_name is already in the same form, then it should work.  Please let me know what the new_name parameter looks like.

Comment: @Chriss Gregg
elif a==4:
        x=input("New Customer Name:")
        print (addingcustomer("customerlist.txt",x))
it is a str type.. probably i need to change it to list.. sorry. Im going to try again

Comment: @Yuvin Ng -- What about all the other information you wanted to add (e.g., "Douiglas College, 77238")

Comment: now currently im figuring out just how to add the name 1 st. douglas college is a string while 77238 is an integer.

Comment: @Yuvin Ng -- well, hopefully this has gotten you started.  You'll need to think about how to parse the input from the file to see if the name exists, and then to output the rest of the data as well.  I've amended the answer to work for a single string name only.

Comment: Yeah it work for string. Anyway thanks for your help. 
just so you know. My plan now is to create a variable with an empty list when customer does not exist.When customer does not exist. it will ask the use to type in the information which will be arranged in the empty list and when it is done. it will add to the customer.txt at the end.

Comment: @Yuvin Ng -- that sounds good.  Again, it is a little tricky when you're dealing with a file, because you have to make sure the information goes into the file in a particular way, and then you have to parse it properly when it comes out.  I think you should not write anything in the function you've provided, and just return `True` if the person exists, and `False` if not.  In another function, you can write the new information.  Good luck!

Comment: i show you what i've done 
def addingcustomer(file_name,new_name):
    f=open(file_name,"r+")
    for line in f:
        if new_name in line:
            f.close()
            return False
    
    x=new_name
    y=input("new custumer id number:")
    z=input("company name:")
    w=input("phone number:")
    A=[y,x,z,w]

    f.write(str(A)+"\n")
    
    f.close()
    return True