# Delete a matching line from a .txt file using python

Tags: python, file, text-files

I'm creating a delete function.

my customerlist.txt

```
[1. 'Yuvin Ng', 'Columbia College', 778]
[2, 'Ali', 'Douiglas College', 77238]
[3, 'Nancy', 'Douglas College', 7783390222]
```

If I want to delete Yuvin Ng and its whole line, how can I do it?

My plan was to create an empty list which will return the whole thing as "" and save it back into the .txt file.

my code

```
def deletecustomer(file_name,name):
    f=open(file_name,"r+")
    c=""
    for line in f:
        if name in line:
      - - - -- - --  -  -- #how can i make it read every line at position list[0] from list
     - ------ -- - -- - - -#take the selected list of the and erase by replacing the whole list with " "
```

I can't come up with any way to solve this problem.

Comment: "Your" code looks a lot like [Chris Gregg's code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638595/how-do-i-make-a-while-loop-so-it-reads-through-every-single-line-in-txt-file-bef/6638614#6638614). Please don't expect StackOverflow to *do* your homework for you!

Comment: @Yuvin Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, but please note that obvious homework questions are always frowned upon here on SO. Don't get me wrong, if you're doing homework, and is stumped, we'd love for you to use SO to get help, but you seem to be working through a larger problem and is asking every step on the way. At this point my advice would be to talk to your classmates and get help from them. If *you* is having problems with these tasks, no doubt others in your class have too. If you continue to leave questions every step on the way, some of them *will* be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to return content of the file minus the deleted line

```
ret = []
for line in f:
    if name != line[1]:
        ret.append(line);
return ret
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_file = open(nf,'w')
with open(fn) as f:
    for l in f:
        if not 'Yuvin Ng' in l:
            new_file.write(l)
```